# Google Cloud Compute, using environment variables

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-launcher

I have found lots of information on how to use environment variables in Google App Engine projects.

However I am yet to find some best practice on what to do with environment variables on compute engine.

Is it possible to use **Google Cloud Deployment Manager** to achieve this? My main goal is to simplify deployment between prod/stag/dev.

Right now I am moving towards using dotenv files.

Stack is webpack 4, express, node 10, vuejs 2.

Answer (score 3):

For Compute Engine instances I'd suggest to use custom metadata. You can find detailed documentation about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata). From within your instance, you can access your custom metadata by performing an empty request to the instance().get method, for example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/instances/example-instance
```

Now, to set your custom metadata, you can indeed use the Google Cloud Deployment Manager. As per the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/setting-metadata-and-startup-scripts), you just need to add the metadata property and the relevant metadata keys and values for your VM resource, for example:

```
resources:
- name: my-first-vm-template
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
   zone: us-central1-a
   machineType:
   ...[snip]...
   metadata:
     items:
     - key: custom-key
       value: "custom-value"
```

Comment: Hey LundinCast, your second link is dead.